# swift exif informations like iOS Camera App

Tags: ios, swift, exif

Is there an easy way to take a photo with exif informations like the standard iOS Camera App and save it to photo album?

```
     try? PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {

            let creationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
            // Set metadata location
            if let location = self.locationManager?.latestLocation {
                creationRequest.location = location
            }

        }
```

is not saving location informations to exif.

I tried the following solution

[add GPS metadata dictionary to image taken with AVFoundation in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116013/add-gps-metadata-dictionary-to-image-taken-with-avfoundation-in-swift/38472100#38472100)

I could save basic exif informations using AVCapture but inserting location informations did not work.

I can not believe that there is no easier way.

Comment: Why don't you add the exif info before creating your PHAsset?

Comment: Note that if you use image picker you wouldn't need to add the location to the PHAsset

Comment: If I use image picker to take photo I have to add location information using LocationManager. This is working but I don't know how to add location informations to EXIF.